# Disk naming clash. Disk name mysteriously changed from Global-Docs-Ext4 to Global-Docs-Ext41, now different from volume name Global-Docs-Ext4

Tags: partitioning, disk, mountpoint

HP ProBook 6360b, Memory 3.8 GB, Intel core i5, Intel HD graphics 3500, Disk 1TB, OS Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, 64 bit, Gnome 3.36.8, Window Sys X11

I have a separate partition on my Ubuntu laptop for documents called 'Global-Docs-Ext4' and by accident, I don't know how, it has become 'Global-Docs-Ext41'.
[image: Pic-0].
[Pic-1]

When mounted I look at its properties by clicking on the drop down arrow by its name at the top left of the file manager where it's name is shown as 'Global-Docs-Ext41'..
[image: Pic-3]

As it is editable, if I delete the '1' from the name I receive the error message 'The name 'Global-Docs-Ext4' is already used in this location. Please use a different name.'.
[image: Pic-3]
When I try to load Firefox, since my profile is originally on 'Global-Docs-Ext4', it will not run with an error message saying my 'profile is inaccessible or cannot be found'. [image: Pic-4]

Another image shows the two contesting objects, this is from 'Disc Usage'. It's the third entry down which needs changing  from '41' back to '4'.
[image]

I have attempted to solve this using a live disk via 'Disks' and 'Gparted' with no success, also searched high and low on the Internet.

Any assistance it resolving this name clash and returning to a consistent 'Global-Docs-Ext4' would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean your partition "is called" Global-Docs-Ext41? Is that a disk label? A mount point? A directory?

Comment: There are no pics or links in your post at all.

Comment: It look to me like you are confusing partition labels and mount points. How are you mounting /dev/sda5? I think you just need to unmount and change the name of the folder to which it is mounted to Global-Docs-Ext4. Then remount. Alternatively use the Firefox profile manager to adjust the location of your profile

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It is not really that I can't run Firefox, more that the all files on that partition are not available as normal, I used FF as an example. The partition is mounted as follows: /media/bb/Global-Docs-Ext4. I still don't know where the '1' in '41' came from. Solution pending.

Comment: There is only one file on there showing at that position and there should be thousands more. I still don't know where the '1' in '41' came from. Solution pending.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try opening a terminal and issue the command `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /media/bb/Global-Docs-Ext4` Assuming that works I will help you fix this permanently.

Update; You fstab file is not the mechanism through which you are mounting Global-Docs-Ext4. The mount point suggests that it is/was originally a usb connected drive of some sort. I can reproduce your issue if the directory /media/John/FLASH DRIVE exists before plugging in the usb device. Normally my flash drive would mount automatically at that point but if the directory exists it mounts at /media/John/FLASH DRIVE1. If it didn’t do that any files at /media/user/FLASH DRIVE would be hidden by the mounted volume. I assume this is by design when auto-mounting usb devices, something similar happens in Arch. This doesn't happen if you explicitly mount a partition with the mount command

What is unclear is why and how a partition that is part of an internal hard is being mounted at /media/bb/Global-Docs-Ext4. Perhaps that data was originally on a usb drive and you have tried to maintain the same mount point when it was moved to a larger internal drive. If this is the case perhaps someone set it up for you.

Happy to help if you get any further problems with this. Just add a comment to the question or answer.

Comment: When I asked you “How are you mounting /dev/sda5?” you told me where you are mounting it. I was after the mechanism being used to mount it. There is probably an entry in your /etc/fstab file that does it at boot. If you still want to understand this add the contents of /etc/fstab and the output of `mount -t ext4` to your question

Comment: mount -t ext4:     bb@bb-HP-ProBook-6360b:~$ mount -t ext4
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)

Comment: # /etc/fstab: static file system information.

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=7b1e975d-b4d9-4916-83ff-5114c2031d4c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=0e41936f-a031-4e36-a8a9-beeed99f8095 none            swap    sw              0       0

Answer (score 0):

Well I never! That last photo gave me an idea. I'd got a backup of the HDD so, since the mysterious folder labelled 'Global-Docs-Ext4' had only 1 entry I deleted it, then tried renaming the third entry down from '41'to it's original '4'. No Luck!....but forgot it was still mounted. However, after unmounting it it magically renamed itself to 'Global-Docs-Ext4'.

Comment: Thank you Ponjar for your guidance to an answer.

Comment: No problem, I’ve learnt something about the auto-mounting of usb drives through this question. On reflection I suspect the drive with the partition you were having the problem with is actually connected via usb. Is that the case?

Comment: Interestingly, no, it's a partition of my laptop SSD.

Comment: Well that is a mystery. Are you using systemd to mount it?

Comment: No, I'm not, just the Nautilus user interface from 'other places' at the bottom left. It appears as an unmounted partition at startup and I mount it manually when I need it.